# OpenLayers: Change point colour to indicate number of overlapping points

Tags: openlayers, heat-map, kernel-density

I would like to have a heatmap that represents the number of overlapping points, basically to achieve the exact same thing as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093935/r-scatter-plot-symbol-color-represents-number-of-overlapping-points) post, but in OpenLayers. At the moment I'm using opacity as an indicator, but that falls off after a certain point.

So for example, I would like to achieve a graph like this:

[image]

And at the moment I have a map like this:

[image]

How would I be able to create this effect?

(Images courtesy of the linked stack post)

Here is my current code in olmap.js:

```
const points = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('points-data').textContent);
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(
        points,
        {featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",}
    ),
});
const vectorStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 3,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.25)', //TODO try with lower opacity instead of outline to show high concentrations

        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.25)',
            width: 0,
        }),
    }),
});

//TODO think about using mask for plotting occurrence density on each area

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: vectorStyle,
});

console.log(points);

const map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'ol-map-container',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url:'http://{1-4}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            })
        }),
        vectorLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-3.1883, 55.9533]),
        zoom: 8,
        extent: [-9990037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 9990037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244], //TODO note that this is a janky solution so that map is not  horizontally bounded (kind of)
        minZoom: 2,
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you seen this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html)?

Comment: @JGH I have! It doesn't exactly fit what I'm looking for though, because ideally I would not like it to be blurry, and when I set the blur of the heatmap to none it looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/aBPzjFE). Am I approaching the heatmap settings wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reproduce the OL heatmap [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html).

An important setting which is not detailed there is the `weight` setting. If not set, it defaults to 1, which basically means to display every point in red, the default max-value color.

If you want 10 or more stacked points to be in red, put a weight of 0.1, doing so will allow coloring points being near 1 to 9 other points in different colors, from green to dark orange by default.

Each feature's weight should be between 0 and 1 (other values will be truncated to either 0 or 1)

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much!! The weight parameter was confusing me because it wants a function for some reason. Thank you for taking the time to answer! :)

Comment: Great! You can still use a function though, like in the example. You can even combine the two approaches (well, still inside a single function): scale between 0-1 according to your function, then reduce by X % so that Y stack points of the highest score are displayed in red.

Comment: I see, that's very helpful! I would like to scale it so that only the maximums are shown as the brightest red but I can figure that out. Do you have any advice for if it would be possible to do a dynamic legend along with the heatmap?

Comment: with heatmaps, 2 "half" values is the same as 1 "full", so even with some scaling you will end up with some red if many points are near each others. Feel free to post a new question with all the relevant details/code

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thanks so much again!!

Comment: Sorry, I had a follow-up thought. Do you know if there's a way to achieve a similar effect without using ol's heatmap? So that overlapping points aren't "additive" and instead map to a colormap ramp depending on number of overlapping points?

Comment: @Riverendell have a look at clusters, with a small distance. This [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html) varies by size and color depending on the number of nearby features. Alternatively, you can pre-compute the color/overlap count